# Posicionar cursor sobre un valor y que muestre un cuadro con una tabla html y css

Tags: html, css

tengo el siguiente dato:

```html
Cambios: <b style="border-style:inset solid;border-width:2px;border-color:#ff6900;padding:0.2em 0.7em;">2</b>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1 Cambio</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2 Giro</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Como puedo hacer para que al colocar el cursor sobre el **2** me despliegue alli mismo la tabla que tiene los datos de cambio 1 y giro 2.

Seria algo parecido a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de que manera podría hacerlo con css y html? muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda que me puedan aportar.

Comment: Si quieres añadir funcionalidad debes de hacerlo con Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimado, primero debemos saber varias cosas, lo que tu quieres hacer se llama "Hacer un Tooltip en CSS " .

En la siguiente imagen te dejo como ejemplo un Tooltip:
[image: Ejemplo de Tooltip 1]

**Pero que es un Tooltip?:**
Un tooltip proporciona información extra cuando el usuario pasa el cursor sobre un elemento.

En HTML Como se vería nuestro codigo :

```
<div class="tooltip top">Posa el ratón encima de mi
<span class="tiptext">Texto del tooltip</span>
</div>
```

En CSS como se veria nuestro codigo:

```
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
.tooltip .tiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 6px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.tooltip .tiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
}
.tooltip:hover .tiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Ahora debes agregar los CSS para las posiciones.

**CSS para Tooltip arriba**

```
.tooltip.top .tiptext{
    margin-left: -60px;
    bottom: 150%;
    left: 50%;
}
.tooltip.top .tiptext::after{
    margin-left: -5px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border-color: #2E2E2E transparent transparent transparent;
```

**CSS para Tooltip abajo**

```
.tooltip.bottom .tiptext{
    margin-left: -60px;
    top: 150%;
    left: 50%;
}
.tooltip.bottom .tiptext::after{
    margin-left: -5px;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border-color: transparent transparent #2E2E2E transparent;
```

**CSS para Tooltip izquierda**

```
.tooltip.left .tiptext{
    top: -5px;
    right: 110%;
}
.tooltip.left .tiptext::after{
    margin-top: -5px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 100%;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #2E2E2E;
```

**CSS para Tooltip derecha**

```
.tooltip.right .tiptext{
    top: -5px;
    left: 110%;
}
.tooltip.right .tiptext::after{
    margin-top: -5px;
    top: 50%;
    right: 100%;
    border-color: transparent #2E2E2E transparent transparent;
```

si todo esto no te sirvió acá te dejo un link con mas informacion: [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp)

Comment: perfecto me funciono perfectamente muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Mira este ejemplo y adaptalo
[ejemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip)

Adaptacion.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">



<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <table class="tooltiptext">
  <tr>
    <td>1 Cambio</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2 Giro</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/215312)

Comment: hare lo posible

Comment: @PacManProgramador muchas gracias por tu respuesta, también es útil. gracias por tu tiempo.